# am having this error report when trying to run my flutter application to my device

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860)' to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
  >   Execution failed for Aapt2Extractor: C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\aapt2\3.5.0-5435860\e8565f11a238b905299000292dded060de0317ea\aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows.jar.
  >   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c5a4a6d176b090b56aa3954ad04c2af5\aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org